# Unable to send email from godaddy server to godaddy or zoho mail

Tags: php, email, server

I am trying to send email from my website to my godaddy mail and zoho mail but its not working.
I tried it on my gmail account and its working fine.
I am using phpmailer.
MY CODE-

```
require_once "PHPMailerAutoload.php";

//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//From email address and name
$mail->From = "test@deltware.com";
$mail->FromName = "Himanshu Mishra";


$mail->addAddress("my godaddy webmail"); //Recipient name is optional

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Please help!!!!!

Comment: can you post full code? Seems it's not full code. Zoho & godaddy has different settings for phpmailer what you would like to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `From` syntax is wrong
Instead of

```
$mail->From = "test@deltware.com";
$mail->FromName = "Himanshu Mishra";
```

It should be

```
$mail->setFrom('test@deltware.com', 'Himanshu Mishra');
```

Check this link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer